# Does Google Dialogflow custom payloads have a Call Function in Telegram?

Tags: dialogflow-es, telegram

I had integrated Dialogflow in both Facebook Messenger & Telegram. In FB messenger, when a user press a button, it will opens the user's phone dialing pad and calls the number. Here's the code:

```
 //FB Messenger code

 {
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "text": "Sorry but I didn't quite catch that. If it's urgent, do give us a call instead. Thanks!",
        "buttons": [

          {
            "type": "phone_number",
            "title": "Call Us",
            "payload": "+60123456789"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to i do this in Telegram?? Thanks